# Difference between Base, Schema, and Migration in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord, orm

I am currently trying to use the `activerecord` gem in Ruby but I'm quite confused on how to use the gem. What's the difference of `ActiveRecord::Base`, `ActiveRecord::Schema` and `ActiveRecord::Migration`? And when do I use them?

Comment: @Sergio No im not familiar with rails. Im currently using activerecord with only ruby. Im not using rails since Im not working on a website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up : AR::Base is the skeleton for a model. Your models usually are classes that derives from this one. AR::Schema is, well, for the schema of your db. You can see what it looks like in the file `db/schema.rb`. As for AR::Migration, it's in the name too : it's the skeleton for the migration files that you can find in `db/migrate`. You can check the rails guides & api reference to have more information on them.

Comment: I agree with the answer but I'm not sure the paths given are valid outside a rails context.

Comment: You're right. Didn't notice the question was about "pure" ruby.

Comment: I think the path wont matter to me. what i'm after is just for the meaning and when to use it.